# autoplay first video in results of youtube using python

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, python-3.5

I want to make an app where I search by typing a certain keyword and the program automatically plays the first video in the search results on youtube. How do I get the link for the first video of the search result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code is to prints the link of the first video on a search result you provide to the app.. example :-
run the app .. type hello its me .. then it does it magic.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re
import webbrowser as wb

query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : input()})
html_content = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?"+query_string)
search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
print("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0])
wb.open_new("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}".format(search_results[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated [the answer from Ali.M.Kamel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51917720).

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re
import webbrowser as wb

query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : input()})
html_content = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com.hk/results?"+query_string)
search_results = re.findall(r'url\"\:\"\/watch\?v\=(.*?(?=\"))', html_content.read().decode())
if search_results:
 print("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0])
 wb.open_new("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}".format(search_results[0]))
```